# calculating not perfect circles

Tags: java, android, math

I want to create a genrator of "not perfect circles", circles that are a bit twisted and more random, but still look a bit like circle or maybe a cloud.

This is what I mean by not perfect circles:
[image]

I want to create a function that gets the maximum and minimum scale of the "not perfect circle" and gets all of its points. I know the formula of a circle:
X^2+Y^2=R^2 but I cant think of a way to make it a bit more random.  Anyone has any ideas?

Edit: trying to draw a perfect circle with points but it wont work:

```
    for (int step = 0; step < 300; ++step) {
         double t = step / 300 * 2 * Math.PI;
         c.drawPoint(300+(float)(33 * Math.cos(t)), 300+(float)(33 * Math.sin(t)), p);
    }
```

Edit 2:

```
    for (int step = 0; step < 20; ++step) {
          double t = step / 20.0 * 2 * Math.PI; 
          double imperfectR = 50.0+randInt(10, 50);
          //I do it here?
          points[step]=new PointF();
          points[step].set((300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.cos(t))), 300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.sin(t)));
          if(step==0){
                pp.moveTo(points[step].x, points[step].y);
          }
          else
                pp.quadTo(points[step-1].x, points[step-1].y,points[step].x, points[step].y);

    }
```

Edit 3:

```
double t=0;
for (int i = 0; i < points.length/4; i++) {
        if(t==1){
            t=0;
        }
        t+=0.10;
        double imperfectR=0.5*((2*points[i+1].y)+(-points[i].y+points[i+2].y)*t+(2*points[i].y-5*points[i+1].y+4*points[i+2].y-points[i+3].y)*(t*t)+((-points[i].y+3*points[i+1].y-3*points[i+2].y+points[i+3].y)*(t*t*t)));
        newPoints[i].set((300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.cos(t))), 300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.sin(t)));
        t+=0.10;
        imperfectR=0.5*((2*points[i+1].y)+(-points[i].y+points[i+2].y)*t+(2*points[i].y-5*points[i+1].y+4*points[i+2].y-points[i+3].y)*(t*t)+((-points[i].y+3*points[i+1].y-3*points[i+2].y+points[i+3].y)*(t*t*t)));
        newPoints[i+1].set((300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.cos(t))), 300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.sin(t)));
        t+=0.10;
        imperfectR=0.5*((2*points[i+1].y)+(-points[i].y+points[i+2].y)*t+(2*points[i].y-5*points[i+1].y+4*points[i+2].y-points[i+3].y)*(t*t)+((-points[i].y+3*points[i+1].y-3*points[i+2].y+points[i+3].y)*(t*t*t)));
        newPoints[i+2].set((300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.cos(t))), 300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.sin(t)));
        t+=0.10;
        imperfectR=0.5*((2*points[i+1].y)+(-points[i].y+points[i+2].y)*t+(2*points[i].y-5*points[i+1].y+4*points[i+2].y-points[i+3].y)*(t*t)+((-points[i].y+3*points[i+1].y-3*points[i+2].y+points[i+3].y)*(t*t*t)));
        newPoints[i+3].set((300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.cos(t))), 300+(float)(imperfectR  * Math.sin(t)));
        if(i==0){
            pp.moveTo(newPoints[i].x, newPoints[i].y);
        }
        pp.lineTo(newPoints[i].x, newPoints[i].y);
        pp.lineTo(newPoints[i+1].x, newPoints[i+1].y);
        pp.lineTo(newPoints[i+2].x, newPoints[i+2].y);
        pp.lineTo(newPoints[i+3].x, newPoints[i+3].y);

}
pp.close();
```

Comment: simple approach: calculate N points, which satisfy circle equation -> randomly increase/decrease each coordinate in a range [0, sigma] -> draw the path using these modified points.

Comment: Maybe look into circular harmonics, i.e. adding to the radius using a weighted sum of randomly-chosen sine waves whose frequency is such that an exact number of cycles fit into the circumference?

Comment: @nikis but if I want to make it a bit more smoother, like if I will random each point the circle might turn to look like a spike ball, not a circle.

Comment: @AndyTurner that sounds really complicated.. how do I do that?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep it depends on N and sigma.

Comment: @nikis Yes it depends on N, but if I randomly increase and decrease it wont look smooth, and what is sigma?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep sigma is maximum allowed deviance. But I agree, this approach is not perfectly fits you needs.

Comment: @SpoocyCrep you can express the circle via the parametric equations $\theta(t) = t$ and $r(t) = R$, where $t$ is your parameter in the range $[0..2\pi)$. You can adjust the radius for a given $t$, e.g. $r'(t) = R + \sum_i A_i\cos(it + w_i)$. Just choose your $A_i$ and $w_i$ values randomly.

Comment: @AndyTurner Uh, that really looks like chinese for me, I apologize but I didn't understand a thing, I'm still an high school student so I might've not reached these kinds of stuff, but what is '$' or theta or t?

Comment: Unfortunately SO doesn't render LaTeX like I expected :( Basically, anything between the dollars is math. `\cos` is the cosine function.

Comment: @AndyTurner Please post an answer with an easier to read formation and also how to use it to get each point of the not perfect circle, ill be very grateful!

Comment: the easiest is to use DiscretePathEffect but the result may be not as smooth as you want, otherwise use bezier curves but it requires some math skills...

Comment: @pskink but the patheffect wont actually change the points of the circle, only it look, or am I mistaking?

Comment: yes,  isn't it what you want?

Comment: @pskink No, I dont want to draw the circle with this shape, I want to just get the points of this shape so I could achieve this effect: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29240327/4024143

Comment: so google for "random curve" like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661653/how-to-generate-this-kind-of-random-curves

Comment: @pskink as I said on the other question I dont want it to fly in random curve, because the bird is only one example, I need this effect for many other things like text wiggling smoothly, or mobs that float, and more stuff like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73778/discussion-between-spoocycrep-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink Lets discuss it at least here, I will try the code you have given, and I have no idea how to implement the catmull in android, im not that good with math and all of these stuff look really complicated to me..

Comment: @SpoocyCrep use your google,  Luke,  there is a lot of pages with the complete formula

Comment: @pskink I know how to use google, but I have hard time reading formulas like these, it looks like chinese for me..

Comment: @SpoocyCrep feed google with "catmull rom algorithm" : the first two are wikipedia articles with theory, the second two are practical sites with working code (e.g. "Splines, Catmull-Rom algorithm for smooth movement")

Comment: @pskink but those are not written in java and doesnt fit android, its hard to understand some parts of the code and translate them to android..

Comment: @pskink also what is SpringSystem? it doesnt exist in android I believe

Comment: @SpoocyCrep It comes with rebound library,  thats why catmull rom splines are better since they only take 30 lines of code and are much more smooth and realistic

Comment: @pskink well I dont understand how to do it. I understand that for you its easy and it would take you only 30 lines of code, but I don't understand how to do it in android. If you dont want to help me I dont see the point of teasing me by telling me its easy and simple..

Comment: @SpoocyCrep did you read the fourth link from google search: http://www.dxstudio.com/guide_content.aspx?id=70a2b2cf-193e-4019-859c-28210b1da81f , whats unclear in `Output_point = P0 ...` this is the exact formula!

Comment: @pskink its written in javascript so its really confusing.. ill try again I guess..

Comment: @pskink what is vector?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep a line with a starting and ending point

Comment: @pskink how do I do that in android?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep you dont need to translate that sample javascript code to java, just use the formula that is at the beginning of that page: `Output_point = P0 ... etc`

Comment: that formulla is also in a third link in modified form: http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/ (see Equation 2) `q(t) = 0.5 *...`

Comment: @pskink I still dont understand. Ok so I get this output_point\desired point, what do I do with it now? what is it exactly?

Comment: it is a formula for getting the y value of the curve input parameter is in range <0..1>

Comment: @pskink but I still need the other points, what do I do with this one? how do I draw the curve?

Comment: this formula gives you imperfectR (see answer below)

Comment: @pskink Ohhh, but why in range 0 to 1?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep because Catmull-Rom splines work that way

Comment: @pskink Wait, I just got completely confused. what do I exactly put in the formula, I mean its in a for, each point until the current point or what?

Comment: For values of t between 0 and 1 the curve passes through P1 at t=0 and it passes through P2 at t=1, To do more than two points just step through the array of points using the previous point, the current point and the next two points as the four points for the spline. For each of these segments draw a curve for 0 < t < 1. This curve will be between the current point and the next point along the whole path

Comment: @pskink but how will I have array of points before having imperfectR, I need imperfectR to draw points, and then use Catmull rom as imperfectR??

Comment: imagine a perfect circle: it has constant radius R all the time,  inperfect circle has to have smootlhly changing radius: R +/- "some small value" what you need is to provide such a smooth function and catmull rom helps here

Comment: @pskink I understand that, and I managed to create imperfect circle with not constant radius. But you tell me that to create imperfect circle i need to use the catmull rom as the R, but also you tell me to get the catmull rom I need all the points (but how the points can exist if there is no R beforehand). you don't see the problem? sigh i'm lost.

Comment: you need to randomly generate sharp function (red one) and then smooth it using catmull rom (green one) http://ctrlv.in/525142 and use a green one as a radius, or see this: http://www.dxstudio.com/wikifiles/14cab67f-70f8-4c3e-873a-b028bf64ef4d.png, you generate randomly red points and then use catmull-rom to make smooth radius

Comment: @pskink Okay, going step by step I generated random sharp shape: http://puu.sh/gQDuX/3078cbdf59.png now, I go each 4 points and use them to draw a curve with catmull-rom? how?

Comment: so you have N radiuses,  so apply catmull-rom for each of them,  btw your N is way too high: i used 20 as N and it looks like this: http://ctrlv.in/524966 or http://ctrlv.in/524967

Comment: @pskink wait I need manually write the t for each one of them?

Comment: yes for each of them call q(t) where t is 0..1

Comment: @pskink so i set random t?

Comment: no,  use 0.1,  0.2 etc

Comment: but if I have 20 steps, and you tell me to go +0.10 each time, what do I do when I reach 1? reset it?

Comment: yes you have to call t = 0, 0.1, 0.2 ... 20 times

Comment: @pskink Okay, do I do it inside the for  I created for creating the shape or I do another for? ill edit in the code I wrote to draw the shape, do I do it there?

Comment: use another for loop

Comment: @pskink Okay, I tried it, it drew nothing, I did how I understood you, ill post it in the queston in edit 3

Comment: @pskink actually my bad, I didnt set the points correctly, I did now and it drew: http://puu.sh/gQMfh/f1becbe8dc.png also edited edit 3 to the code im using now

Comment: ok it seems you will not do that: then see this http://pastebin.com/FuCUMZvq

Comment: @pskink THANK YOU, please post this as answer so I could mark it as done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative equation for a circle which is a bit easier to draw is one of its parametric forms:

```
x = R * cos(t);
y = R * sin(t);
```

where `R` is the nominal radius and `t` is a parameter between `0` and `2 * pi`. So, you can draw points on the circumference a 'perfect' circle like this:

```
for (int step = 0; step < NSTEPS; ++step) {
  double t = step / (double) NSTEPS * 2 * pi;
  drawPoint(R * cos(t), R * sin(t));
}
```

You can make the circle 'imperfect' by adding on a random amount to the circle's radius, as suggested by @nikis:

```
for (int step = 0; step < NSTEPS; ++step) {
  double t = step / (double) NSTEPS * 2 * pi;
  double imperfectR = R + randn();  // Normally distributed random
  drawPoint(imperfectR * cos(t), imperfectR * sin(t));
}
```

However, this is probably going to give you very spiky shape, since there is nothing to make the radius at `step` and `step + 1` similar. Without losing generality, you can rewrite the code above as:

```
for (int step = 0; step < NSTEPS; ++step) {
  double t = step / (double) NSTEPS * 2 * pi;
  double imperfectR = f(t);
  drawPoint(imperfectR * cos(t), imperfectR * sin(t));
}
```

Where `f(t)` is some function generating the radius for parameter `t`. Now, you can choose absolutely any function for `t`, but you probably want to choose something which is continuous over the circle, i.e. there is no point where `f(t)` changes value suddenly.

There are lots of choices here. The example that I suggested above was to suggest using a sum of cosine functions:

```
double f(double t) {
  double f = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    f += A[i] * cos(i * t + w[i]);
  }
  return f;
}
```

where `A` and `w` are randomly-selected values; `A[0]` should be set to `R`. The point here is that the cosine function has a period of `2 * pi`, so `f(alpha) = f(alpha + 2 * pi)`, satisfying the requirement of being continuous.

However, this is far from the only choice. You could maybe choose something like a sum of Gaussian kernels, which places 'bumps' centered at `w[i]` with a spread of `sigma[i]` on the circumference of the circle:

```
double f(double t) {
  double f = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    f += A[i] * exp(-Math.pow(t-w[i], 2) / sigma[i]);
  }
  return f;
}
```

(this doesn't quite work, it doesn't handle the wrap-around of `t`)

You will need to play around and see what function and what sorts of randomly-selected values give you the shape you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your rich answer, Im trying the code now but I fail to draw the perfect circle as shown in the second code, can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73778/discussion-between-spoocycrep-and-pskink please?

Comment: Ill also edit in the code I wrote that fails to draw a circle

Comment: The sum of cosines example for `f` is the way to go (you'd also want to add sines).  By Fourier series, any shape would be possible if you use infinitely many `A` values.  In that sense, cosines and sines are the only choice.

Comment: @Teepeemm but why do I fail to draw a normal circle in the code I edited in the question

Comment: @Teepeemm - you don't need separate sines because of the offset `w[i]` in `cos(i * t + w[i])`. Of course, you can express as `cos(A + B) = a cos A + b sin B`.

Comment: @SpoocyCrep - I suspect that `step / 300 * 2` is always evaluating to zero because all terms are integers and `step < 300`. Try `300.0` to force coercion to a double. (And apologies for writing it in my code...)

Comment: @SpoocyCrep if you really want smooth random curves read this: http://www.antigrain.com/research/bezier_interpolation/

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay, I managed to draw a circle and imperfect circle that is spiky, I'm now trying to understand the f function, what is N? and do I need to manually set random values in A[] and M[]? I didn't really understand that part

Comment: @pskink Thanks, Ill save that solution, for now ill try andy's solution, if that wont work ill try yours

Comment: @SpoocyCrep this is a 10 minute work, not perfect, but perfectly random and perfectly smooth: http://ctrlv.in/524483

Comment: @pskink nice! well if so ill be happy to see how you did it

Comment: @SpoocyCrep just implemented the idea frm the link i sent

Comment: @pskink it looks complicated and some parts of the code doesnt exist in android.. It also doesnt exactly show how to create a circle type shape, but smooth any kind of shape.. meaning I need to create random curved shape which is also something that sounds hard. if you already made the app I dont see why cant you share the solution in android o.0.

Comment: @SpoocyCrep its nothing but a simple math,  from Android i only used Math.hypot and Path.moveTo/cubicTo

Comment: I'm pleased that you are making progress, but could you take it to chat?

Comment: @AndyTurner apologize, can you please answer my question "Okay, I managed to draw a circle and imperfect circle that is spiky, I'm now trying to understand the f function, what is N? and do I need to manually set random values in A[] and M[]? I didn't really understand that part"

Comment: @pskink please post your own answer so I could ask you questions or join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73778/discussion-between-spoocycrep-and-pskink

Comment: @SpoocyCrep `A` and `w` are values that you need to choose... somehow. There is some math which you can use to calculate their values for an example shape (and I think it is quite beautiful); you should read up about Fourier Series and orthogonality of sinusoids. If you're not going to dig deeper into the math, I recommend that you pick random values which get smaller for larger `i`. `N` is a term which you need to pick - the higher it is, the "rougher" the shape can be, but then the more coefficients `A` and `w` you need to calculate. Good luck!

Comment: @SpoocyCrep here http://pastebin.com/D3u8CmDY you have the solution not using bezier curves, your job is to join start & end points of the curve

Comment: @SpoocyCrep found out that Catmull-Rom slines are *WAY* better in smooth interpolation of random points,  google "catmull rom spline" for more info, the result is much more **realistic**